# Super Sample Superstore Tutorial

Tags: tableau-api

Hi I am new to tableau and I am trying to create a similar version of visualization as the super sample superstore on the website. https://www.tableau.com/solutions/gallery/super-sample-superstore
I am wondering is there any training materials or tutorials regarding to this sample. if not, a specific question on this is how the three navigating buttons on the top right were created and how the perimeters where created to link to different DASHBOARDS.

```
descriptive/prescriptive/annotations
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn tableau from https://www.tableau.com/learn/training

Hear you can find all information with videos.